# Linq expression for left join and filter for the inner table

Tags: linq, join, subquery, left-join

I want to know how to make Linq expression that has the same effect as these SQL query

```
SELECT item.*, priceforitem.*
FROM
  item
  LEFT JOIN priceforitem
    ON priceforitem.ItemID = item.ItemID
    AND priceforitem.PriceID = ?PriceID
```

I already make it using the Method query but I don't know if it will produce the same result

```
db.Items
    .GroupJoin(
        db.PriceForItems.Where(pi => pi.PriceID == id),
        i => i.ItemID,
        pi => pi.ItemID,
        (i, pi) => new { Item = b, Prices = pi })
    .SelectMany(
        a => a.Prices.DefaultIfEmpty(),
        (i, pi) => new
        {
            ItemID = i.Item.ItemID,
            Code = i.Item.Code,
            Name = i.Item.Name,
            PriceForItemID = pi.PriceForItemID,
            Price = pi.Price 
        })
```

and then after thinking for awhile i shorten it like this

```
db.Items
    .SelectMany(
        i => db.PriceForItems.Where(
            pi => pi.PriceID == id 
                && pi.ItemID = i.ItemID).DefaultIfEmpty(),
        (i, pi) => new 
        {
            ItemID = i.Item.ItemID,
            Code = i.Item.Code,
            Name = i.Item.Name,
            PriceForItemID = pi.PriceForItemID,
            Price = pi.Price 
        })
```

I am new to Linq, and I don't know which is better and how to convert it to Linq query statement.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your sql query. It is effectively and inner join because the where condition will filter out all rows where data from `priceforitem` is null. If you do want to convert same query to linq you can do it like
from i in db.Items

```
join p in db.PriceforItems on
i.ItemId equals p.ItemId into tempvals
from t in tempvals.DefaultIfEmpty()
where t.PriceId == id
select new{i.ItemId, ..., t.PriceId, t...., t....}
```

I mostly write linq queries instead of expressions where they are more readable to me. If you still want to get an expression, you can write a valid linq query and paste it into [Linqpad](http://www.google.com.pk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFkQFjAA&url=http://www.linqpad.net/&ei=m5DQT7esOcXqrQfozY3_Cw&usg=AFQjCNFw-ZpPkP4je7u9udiur5Wg5us7tQ&sig2=qCRPnsfxPj2F8OEunnHoDg) and it will give the result as well as lambda expression of your query.

Comment: I'm just not sure with the `where t.PriceId == id` part, will it affects the resulting rows by filtering out `t` whose `tempvals` is empty. Is the operator precedence of `where` is greater than the second `from`? I'm affraid it will have the same result as if my first SQL query with the last `AND priceforitem.PriceID = ?PriceID` replaced with `WHERE priceforitem.PriceID = ?PriceID`.

Comment: `from t in tempvals.DefaultIfEmpty()` is used for outer join and `when` is used to filter the result.